# Random output at the end of gloss entries

Tags: glossaries, gloss

I'm getting a weird output at the end of gloss entries. When I remove that entry, all of a sudden that output seems to just be floating randomly and I cannot find the source.

The input will be:

```
@gd{abbreviationsandacronyms,
word = {abbreviations and acronyms},
definition = {A few universally recognized abbreviations are required (and preferred) in some circumstances, such as TA or RA. Some others are acceptable depending on the context. But in general, do not use abbreviations or acronyms which the reader would not quickly recognize.\par
Acronyms should be capitalized with no periods in front of the letters. There should be a period at the end of abbreviations, such as Dem. for Democrat.\par
Do not follow an organization's full name with an abbreviation or acronym in parentheses or set off by dashes. If an abbreviation or acronym would not be clear on second reference without this arrangement, do not use the abbreviation or acronym.\par
For time references, use am and pm without periods. For more help, see \g{timeanddatereferences}.\par
In numbered addresses, use the abbreviations Ave., Blvd., and St. for numerical addresses: \emph{1600 Pennsylvania Ave.} In all other cases, fully spell out the street name.}
}
```

And the output will be:

[image]

with the number being apparently random in each case. e.g. ", p. 1."

I'm using the package gloss.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I looked through the gloss style sheet and added:

```
\renewcommand\glosspage[1]{}
```

to my preamble and it disappeared. Anyone see a problem with this command?

Comment: I can't imagine it will be a problem if you don't want the page numbers in the glossary. I don't know the package but that's how I read the documentation, at least. And it is intended as a user command which can be redefined as you wish so it should be reasonably safe provided the package is reasonably designed.